# Spark - Parquet or Delta - files size explodes

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, parquet, delta-lake

I replace 2 Integer columns by 1 Integer column, using an inner-join. After that, my DataFrame is 20-times the original size when writing parquet/delta from PySpark.

My inital Spark DataFrame has ~15 columns and 2 of them are Integer ID-columns (ID1 and ID2), meaning they are just for reference.

Now I want to map them to a single ID column. To do this I create a mapping table:
ID1 | ID2 | ID
Then I do an inner-join, and drop ID1 and ID2.

Here is the code for this step:

I create a mapping from ID1 + ID2 => ID by this table:

```
my_index = df
  .groupBy(['ID1','ID2'])
  .count()
  .withColumn("ID",F.row_number()
  .over(Window.partitionBy().orderBy(F.col("count").desc())))
```

And then I replace ID1 + ID2 by ID using an inner join:

```
df_new = df
  .join(my_index, ['ID1','ID2'], 'inner')
  .drop('ID1','ID2')
```

After this: df_new is 20-times the file-size of df (same number of rows). All the following steps get very slow then. Any suggestion how to fix this or just how to understand what is going on?

I tried many things to figure out what is going wrong:

- I dropped some columns, still there is this factor 20 explosion
- I tried Parquet and I tried Delta... no difference
- Instead of adding the ID column, I just added some random Integers, this was better, the size increased only by +30%
- I did not drop the ID1 and ID2, because maybe they help to compress the file-size, this did not help
- After the factor 20 explosion, I dropped the new ID columns again, but the DataFrame was still approx. the same size.

More details: I'm working on big datasets, ~3.000.000.000 records but the columns are small, mainly integers + timestamps.

If someone knows the solution, I would be super happy. Also if you just have an idea how to debug this and to understand why the size explodes would help me.

Comment: Can you provide code sample showing what you've done ?

Comment: Sure!

So I create a mapping from ID1 + ID2 => ID by this table:
my_index = df
         .groupBy(['ID1','ID2'])
         .count()
         .withColumn("ID", F.row_number().over(Window.partitionBy().orderBy(F.col("count").desc())))

And then I replace ID1 + ID2 by ID using an inner join:

df_new = df
         .join(my_index, ['ID1','ID2'], 'inner')
         .drop('ID1','ID2')

After this: df_new is 20-times the file-size of df (same number of rows).

Any suggestion how to fix this or just how to understand what is going on?